# No response or Completion Block Skipped AlamofireImage

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

So I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to get AlamofireImages ImageDownloader to work. Below is the function I'm trying to use to download and later cache an image.

I've used normal Alamofire to request images before, however, the project has evolved to include caching an image to the disk to reduce the amount of requests to the server.

```
var downloader: ImageDownloader? 

func downloadAndCacheImage(_ url: String, imageView: UIImageView)
{
    self.downloader = ImageDownloader()

    var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: "GiveMeAResponse.com", method: .get)

    self.downloader?.download(urlRequest) { response in

        switch response.result{
        case .success(let image):
            print("\(image) has been downloaded")
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print("ERROR: \(response.error)")
            break
        }

        if let imageData = response.data{
            debugPrint("Applying image...")
            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData){
                ImageManager.applyImage(imageView: imageView, image: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking through the AlamofireImage documentation [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage), it looks pretty simple to send a download request and I feel as though with what I have I should be getting at least a failure message. The completion block is just getting skipped all together and I'm not entirely sure why unless it has to do with this which is also in the documentation.

> Make sure to keep a strong reference to the ImageDownloader instance, otherwise the completion closure will not be called because the downloader reference will go out of scope before the completion closure can be called.

This might be a bit of a dumb question, but am I not doing the above resulting in the closure not being called?

If anyone has some insight, that would be awesome.

Edit: Included strong reference to the ImageDownloader.

Edit#2: Assigning the download to a variable and printing the response code returns a nil. (Maybe because the request is done on a different thread?)

```
var downloader: ImageDownloader? 

func downloadAndCacheImage(_ url: String, imageView: UIImageView)
{ 
    self.downloader = ImageDownloader()

    var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://solarianprogrammer.com/images/2013/02/28/mandelbrot_piece_Z2.png")!)

    let downloadReciept = self.downloader?.download([urlRequest])
    print(downloadReciept?[0].request.response) // Returns nil

}
```

Edit#3:
I finally fixed it and my code now looks like this:

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader.default
func downloadAndCacheImage(_ url: String, imageView: UIImageView)
{
    var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://solarianprogrammer.com/images/2013/02/28/mandelbrot_piece_Z2.png")!)

    self.downloader.download(urlRequest) { response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let image):
            print("\(image) has been downloaded")
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print("ERROR: \(response.error)")
            break
        }

        if let imageData = response.data{
            debugPrint("Applying image...")
            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData){
                ImageManager.applyImage(imageView: imageView, image: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All I really changed was:

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader()
```

To:

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader.default
```

I really hope this helps anyone who comes across this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by changing my code to the below. For some reason the below line change fixed it.

let downloader = ImageDownloader()

to

let downloader = ImageDownloader.default

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader.default
func downloadAndCacheImage(_ url: String, imageView: UIImageView)
{
    var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://solarianprogrammer.com/images/2013/02/28/mandelbrot_piece_Z2.png")!)

    self.downloader.download(urlRequest) { response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let image):
            print("\(image) has been downloaded")
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print("ERROR: \(response.error)")
            break
        }

        if let imageData = response.data{
            debugPrint("Applying image...")
            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData){
                ImageManager.applyImage(imageView: imageView, image: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes across it!

Comment: Came across and it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
class MyClass
{
    var downloader: ImageDownloader? // This acts as the 'strong reference'.

    ...

    func downloadAndCacheImage(_ url: String, imageView: UIImageView)
    {
        self.downloader = ImageDownloader()

        ...
    }
}
```

because the download happens after your `downloadAndCacheImage()` returns (using other thread(s)).

Your current `downloader` is a local/automatic variable of the `downloadAndCacheImage()`. It is released when `downloadAndCacheImage()` ends. This prematurely stops/cuts the download process.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I really thought it was going to work this time as I tried this but forgot to actually initialize it.. Whoops. For some reason though, the closure is still being skipped. : / 

I'll edit my question to reflect my changes in my code.

Comment: Dit you check if your URL is correct and responds to a GET (for example using `curl`)? Does the downloader not have an error block or a delegate that call an error function?

Comment: My URL is correct as I've tested it through other functions that use the GET method. For the second part of your question, I was hoping it would function the same way Alamofire does and simply prints the error if it failed to get the image.

I switched my code around as well to make sure that it would work using just plain Alamofire and it did indeed work. It's just the ImageDownloader I'm having a problem with. So no, there isn't a delegate that calls an error function.